# HTTP_HOST Windows Azure Websites with custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have WAWS setup with a custom domain and staging. When I try get the server variable HTTP_HOST it always returns sitename-azurewebsites.net. Is there another server variable that contains the custom domain? Also when on staging I would like it to return sitename-staging.azurewebsites.net instead of the custom domain. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP_HOST` will be whatever the client (browser usually) used to hit the site. If you hit your site with sitename.azurewebsites.net then the `HTTP_HOST` will be that, if you hit it from the custom hostname it will be the custom host name. Same thing for the staging slot. If you never setup a custom hostname for the staging slot, then it will always be sitename-staging.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I also thought that, however if I hit my site at www.sitename.com then I still get sitename.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: that's strange because I am getting my custom host name. How are you getting `HTTP_HOST` in your app?

Comment: @Peuge I have the same issue - did you ever figure out why the azure site was getting confused and not using the custom domain?

Comment: have the same problem...is there still no solution for this?